# ansible: promoting warnings to errors

Tags: ansible, warnings

I have some continuous integration checks which run a few `ansible-playbook` commands. Each playbook may be running many plays, including numerous large roles.

Every now and then, somebody introduces some change that causes a warning when `ansible-playbook` runs, e.g. something like this:

```
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters
such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "{{ some_variable}}" not in
some_result.stdout
```

or:

```
[WARNING]: Consider using unarchive module rather than running tar
```

or some deprecation warnings like:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: ec2_facts is kept for backwards compatibility but usage 
is discouraged. The module documentation details page may explain more about 
this rationale.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation 
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

and so on. Sometimes these warnings pop up when we upgrade ansible versions. Regardless of why they happen, I would really like for some way to have the `ansible-playbook` command fail loudly when it causes one of these warnings, instead of quietly proceeding on and having my CI check be successful. Is there any way to do this? I'm using ansible 2.4.3 currently.

I find lots of discussion about ways to **hide** these warnings, but haven't found anything about promoting them to hard errors.

Comment: Really good question as treating warnings as errors could be extremely useful on CI gates as it would force people to fix the code.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42479

Comment: Considering that this is happening in a CI environment, you may want to look into using https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/ as a part of your CI process to look for warnings and other code smells.

Comment: I opened this one -- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/64175 -- if I get some time I will try to work on a Pull Request

Comment: I use `ansible-lint` already, but this doesn't help when for example running playbooks against a non-existent inventory group. In that case ansible prints a warning but no error and the CI test passes. I want it to fail in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem. My workaround is:

- run the playbook with --check and 'tee' to a temporary file
- do some grep-magic to filter out 'WARNING]:'
- do some grep-sed-magic to filter out results that are not zero (except ok/skipped)

I know it is not ideal, so if you came with a nice solution please share :-)

Answer (score -2):

There is an option `any_errors_fatal` in `ansible.cfg`, what about putting

```
any_errors_fatal = True
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for -- `any_errors_fatal` says it "will mark all hosts as failed if any fails". In my case, I have only one target host, but I want any soft warnings against that host to be promoted to hard errors.

Answer (score -4):

To hide such `[DEPRECATION WARNING]` as stated you can
"disabled by setting `deprecation_warnings=False` in ansible.cfg."

But this may not be ideal, As in future you have no visibility of what may change or being depreciated.

If you are absolutely sure that you can ignore such a warning, You can use::

```
args:
 warn: false
```

Or modify your code as suggested in the warning message.

else

If you want to raise error for any warnings, You could register the result and apply `failed_when` like below example.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     - name: Fail if there is any warnings
       shell: touch a.txt
       register: result
       failed_when: result.warnings is defined`
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do the opposite of hiding warnings. I want any warnings to cause a hard error.

Comment: I have edited my answer. To do this, You could register the result and process the warning as per your requirement.

Comment: @Random_Automation To be useful, these warnings would have to be changed to errors globally. If you already know which particular task suffers from a deprecation warning, you no longer need the feature; you can just update the task with whatever the new construct is.

Answer (score -6):

What for? Do they interfere with the implementation of the playbook? Most likely it is not. Just fix the playbook code.

Such a warning to remove as I understood it is either impossible or very difficult (in any case, it did not work for me when I tried):

```
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters
such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "{{ some_variable}}" not in
some_result.stdout
```

Just use:

```
some_variable not in some_result.stdout
```

In the "when" conditions it is not necessary to set {{}} to get the variable value

Personally, I prefer to search through "find":

```
some_result.stdout.find(some_variable) == -1
```

This warning:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: ec2_facts is kept for backwards compatibility but usage 
is discouraged. The module documentation details page may explain more about 
this rationale.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation 
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

can be removed from output by setting:

> deprecation_warnings = false

in the file ansible.cfg

This warn:

```
[WARNING]: Consider using unarchive module rather than running tar
```

Easy to remove if you use the module ansible instead of tar in "command":

```
unarchive: src=file.tgz dest=/opt/dest
```